# Jenkins unable to run periodic/scheduled jobs randomly - "error persisting EventHistoryStore entry file"

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins version - `Jenkins ver. 2.138.3`
OS - `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`

Jenkins sometimes is unable to run cron/scheduled jobs randomly with below error -

```
Jan 25, 2019 12:30:00 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore store
SEVERE: Unexpected error persisting EventHistoryStore entry file.
java.io.IOException: Unexpected error creating channel event log dir /var/lib/jenkins/logs/sse-events/job.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore.getChannelDir(EventHistoryStore.java:205)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore.store(EventHistoryStore.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore$EventHistoryLogger.onMessage(EventHistoryStore.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pubsub.GuavaPubsubBus$GuavaSubscriber$1.run(GuavaPubsubBus.java:137)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:273)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pubsub.GuavaPubsubBus$GuavaSubscriber.onMessage(GuavaPubsubBus.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1831.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:68)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:45)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:313)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.AsyncEventBus.access$001(AsyncEventBus.java:31)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.AsyncEventBus$1.run(AsyncEventBus.java:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jan 25, 2019 12:30:00 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore store
SEVERE: Unexpected error persisting EventHistoryStore entry file.
java.io.IOException: Unexpected error creating channel event log dir /var/lib/jenkins/logs/sse-events/job.
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore.getChannelDir(EventHistoryStore.java:205)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore.store(EventHistoryStore.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.EventHistoryStore$EventHistoryLogger.onMessage(EventHistoryStore.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pubsub.GuavaPubsubBus$GuavaSubscriber$1.run(GuavaPubsubBus.java:137)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:273)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.pubsub.GuavaPubsubBus$GuavaSubscriber.onMessageJan 25, 2019 12:49:55 AM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe there are no privileges to create that directory.

Comment: `/var/lib/jenkins` is owned by `jenkins` user. In that case it should clearly state a permission error. Secondly, this is quite random, doesn't look like a permission error to me on the very first look.